# Correct use CoroutineScope with retrofit api call

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, launch, coroutinescope

Is this correct Coroutine and retrofit use?
i have some problems with interception of service (RuntimeException in geting getAccessTokenBlocking via intercept), and maybe it due to incorrect CoroutineScope use?

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(...){
val service = serviceBuilderFactory
            .create(serviceEndpoint, acc)
            .buildWithCache(Service::class.java)

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
            .launch(exceptionHandler) {
                val obj = service.getObj() 
    //should i use here for webView.post - withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {  ??????
   // or shoud i use async and resume webView.post after callback?

                webView.post {
                    webView.loadUrl(obj.url)
                    }
             }
}
```

retrofit

```
@GET("/url")
suspend fun getObj(): Obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be in an adapter at all. You're firing off coroutines every time an item scrolls onto the screen, and since you create a one-off CoroutineScope to launch each one, you have no means of cancelling them. If the user rotates the screen a couple of times quickly, you'll have like 30 obsolete coroutines running in the background that you can't cancel, and many of them will be doing redundant work.

Instead, you should do the fetching in a ViewModel so the fetches don't have to be repeated redundantly when the screen is rotated. And use `viewModelScope` to launch the coroutines so they'll be automatically cancelled when they become obsolete from the current screen going out of scope.

If you don't mind pre-fetching each item's data before showing it in the RecyclerView, you can map your data type to include the fetched URL before you even expose it to your Activity/Fragment via a LiveData or Flow.

If you want to lazily start loading the URL only when the item appears on screen, you can map your data type to a `Deferred<String>` using `async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { ... }`. Then add a CoroutineScope parameter to your adapter's constructor so the Activity can pass `lifecycleScope` or Fragment can pass `viewLifecycleScope`, and you can use that scope to launch coroutines in the adapter that will automatically be cancelled when obsolete. And you can use these coroutines to `await()` the deferred URL.

Comment: correct answer as usual, but perhaps worth adding that OP might need some form of error handling too, either some form of runCatching or something else

Comment: Good point. Retrofit suspend functions will throw exceptions if anything prevents the data from being fetched, so you need to use try/catch or runCatching.